# Parsing the previous <td> of an element (ignoring other elements inbetween)

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have an extremely long HTML file with many different tables. I want to parse only certain tables, but unfortunately the `<table>` tag is of no help here.

The tables I do want to parse look like this:

```
<tr>
<td> TEXT1 </td>
<td> <a class='unique identifier' ...> TEXT2 </a></td>
</tr>
```

I want both "TEXT1" and "TEXT2". I know how to get "TEXT2": It is always in an `<a>` tag and my solution so far is

```
//a[(@class="unique identifier")]
```

Note: Sometimes "TEXT1" is in a `<p>` tag, sometimes it isn't. Sometimes there are other tags after it like `<b>`s or `<br>`s or `<em>`, etc. I thought that I would need to get the previous `<td>` content, after a every `<a>` that I have found, but ignore any other elements that are inbetween.

How can I tell Nokogiri that for every "TEXT2" that I have found to go back and get the previous `<td>` as well, so that I can get "TEXT1"?

Comment: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: There you may find a way to get tr element

Comment: that's not my problem. have you even read what I asked?

Comment: Yeap. To get both texts you'll need a way to go up on tree (back to the parents of 'a') so that when you reach tr you'll have both tds and thus you will be able to access both texts. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: well, if there is a way to go up again to the <tr>, then YES. but just to go to the <tr> element and then go through the <tds> NO, because there are way to many tables in the HTML I cannot filter out. I do not understand however how this answer you linked to solves my question. First answer to the question you linked to?

Comment: I'm sorry. The answers on that question don't fits your needs despite of same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<tr>
<td> TEXT1 </td>
<td> <a class='uid'> TEXT2 </a></td>
</tr>
EOT

wrapping_tr = doc.at('//a[@class="uid"]/../..')
nodes = wrapping_tr.search('td')

nodes.map(&:text) 
# => [" TEXT1 ", "  TEXT2 "]
```

I'd recommend spending time reading [the XPath documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/) as this is pretty elementary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But: If in `wrapping_tr` there is my `//a[@class="uid"]`, then why am I looking for a `<td>` _within_ that again? Or am I missing something? `puts` gives me only `<a class='uid'> TEXT2 </a>`

Comment: "`If in 'wrapping_tr' there is my '//a[@class="uid"]'`" so you're saying your example isn't accurate and sufficient to explain the problem? Have you read "[mcve]"?

Comment: No, you quoted that perfectly. But it seems we are then searching for `<td>` within the `<a class='uid'> TEXT2 </a></td>`. But we don't need to go deeper, but up again so to speak. Do yo understand what I mean, or is it me who misunderstands something? Thank you again by the way, as a beginner you are helping me out a lot here!!

Comment: Does the output of the example code show the results you asked for? If so, then it appears it does the right thing. And, if so, you should probably read the documentation, especially for how `//` and `..` work in XPaths as those are the keys for what this is doing.

Comment: hey! no, it does not. `wrapping_tr = doc.at('//a[(@class="uid")]')` gives me `<a class='uid'> TEXT2 </a>`. everything after that has nothing as its content.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend providing an accurate and minimal example of the HTML you are talking about as it appears to be different than what you gave us. We can't help you without that; Any attempt to do so without accurate input is a waste of our time and yours.